# post_max_size in php.ini not found

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm trying to change the file upload settings in Apache

I typed the follow commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

(file opend successful)

Ctrl + W  "post_max_size"
but here I get answer : not found

also "upload_max_filesize" not found

Plz help

Comment: No idea of what `Ctrl + W` is supposed to do but... may I suggest you go to the end of the file and type: `p`, `o`, `s`, `t`, `_`... until you get the desired result?

Comment: `Ctrl w` is just "where is" in nano, like Ctrl F in most places

Comment: Try just  Ctrl + W: "post_"

Comment: maybe you can't find it because the key is **not present** in your ``php.ini`` - just write it down O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use vi. And I tried just now, `post_max_size = 8M` is on line 674 in file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.Hope you find.

Comment: And `upload_max_filesize = 2M` is on line 802

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked, I am using Amazon AWS Light Sail where I have to go inside the server file where the path is  `/opt/bitnami/php/etc$ vi php.ini`

Then the Editor will open once you get inside the editor on line 702:

[image]

you will see the `post_max_size = 8M`, here you can increase the size according to your requirement.

Secondly, when it comes to `upload_max_filesize = 2M` it will be on line 820; remember it might change from your hand, so just scroll down and find it.

Once you find that change the size according to your requirements.

Thirdly, once you have done with these above steps than restart your Apache service  by simple writing this command:

```
/opt/bitnami/php/etc$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

or another way to restart all service just write

```
/opt/bitnami/php/etc$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Both work